# GPU causes black screen on boot (new build)

Tags: computer-building, gpu

Making my first build from scratch. I've managed to boot to bios just fine with everything except GPU plugged in, but when I plug in my GFX card, suddenly, black screen.
I've tried both onboard and GPU dvi ports when the GPU is plugged in, but still no signal. As soon as I take out the GPU and switch to onboard graphics I can get into BIOS.

Mobo: http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813157302

CPU: http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16819115233

GPU: http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814125413

PSU: http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817151095

EDIT:
After putting in a different GPU which I know works correctly from my old rig, I discovered that the problem remains. Unless I am mistaken, this means that the problem must be related to the motherboard (or BIOS maybe?). Does it seem possible/likely that the mobo might be DOA so that when a PCI-E device is used, the pc black screens?

Comment: Did you remember to plug the auxiliary power into the card?  Are you sure the card even works?

Comment: Yea, it definitely has power. I am not sure the card works. The fans spin, but that is the only indication that it is working at all. How can I diagnose a DOA GPU?

Comment: I'd try it in another system if you have one handy, but if *everything else* works I'd probably just assume it's DOA and get a replacement.  It could potentially be something else but the odds are not high enough to spend time testing, IMO.

Comment: Sounds like its a hardware conflcit between the motherboard and graphic card.  Based on the power supply you are barely within the power requreiements.

Comment: @Ramhound Why would a 620W be too low for a single-GPU system?

Comment: @MarcusChan - Thats only 70W away from whats required by the GPU by itself? We also don't know what else is contained in the system.  Clearly the problem is either the graphic card.  I only pointed out the system is barely within the power requirements.

Comment: A 7970 GHz has a TDP of only 250W, so not "required by the GPU by itself". And yes, 550W is the suggested PSU, and 650>550. In any case, yeah, I'd RMA the GPU as Shinrai said. My only other guess is it could be an issue with the Lucid Virtu MVP on the mobo.

Comment: I agree with Marcus, this should be enough juice to at least get the damned thing to power on.  GPU virtualization settings are a good thing to check too, though - I'm not familiar with this board but should be an easy BIOS option to find.  (You'd think it'd boot to the onboard anyway, though - this sounds more like it's trying and failing to use the discrete)

Comment: See edit. The GPU doesn't seem to be defective after all!

Comment: Hmm. Have you tried looking in the BIOS like Shinrai said? Also, do you have another mobo to test?